# Windows 8.1 and OAuth2.0 AuthorizeAsync

Tags: windows, google-drive-api

The code below is the code the documentation says to use for Windows 8.1 apps. However, when I make this call, it just hangs and never returns. Any ideas?

```
   var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
   new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/client_secrets.json"),
   Scopes,
   "user",
   CancellationToken.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

When this call is made it should open a browser window and request authentication before returning. Check to ensure it's not silently opening a tab in a existing browser.